# Semantically correct way to modify a Ruby hash - a functional approach?

Tags: ruby, hash, functional-programming

I have to clean up a object in Ruby, and the way I have been doing that is by cloning a hash, and modifying an original. This was my original method:

```
def remove_empty_stories(content)
    content.clone.each do |section,stories|
        for i in 0...stories.length do
            if stories[i].length < 25
          content[section].delete_at(i)
            end
        end
    end
    content
end
```

But I've had a thought that it would be a better idea to rather build up a new hash out of acceptable values from the old hash. Is this a correct assumption?

Am I right in thinking that this would be a 'functional' style?

An example of what content might look like before:

```
content = {
  :GENERAL_STORIES => [
    'Story 1',
    'Story 2',
    '',
    'Story 3',
    etc,
  ],
  :GOLD_STORIES => [
    'Story 1',
    'Story 2',
    'Story 3',
    '',
    '',
    etc
  ],
  etc.
}
```

And what I found with the above method is that if I remove a story then it shortens the array, but the iterator still counts to the original length (and the error I got was that .length cannot be applied to nil or something)

Comment: Can you give us an example about content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be a better idea. Consider situation when this hash is being used by  multiple instances of different classes. When one of this instances modifies hash, change has impact on the rest. Later it is very hard to debug why something does not work.

```
def without_empty_stories(content)
   content.inject({}) do |memo, section, stories|
     memo[section] = stories.select { |s| s.length >= 25 }
     memo
   end
end
```

P.S. I am on Windows right now - sry if any syntax error was introduced

Comment: I've never see the inject syntax before. Thanks. I was finding I was having to use Marshall.load(Marshall.dump(array)) a lot. I guess that it would be better not to use that?

Comment: as to syntax. read a bit on `map, reduce, each, inject` - they are used very often.

and yes - using Marshall here is unrecommended

Comment: `reduce` and `inject` are the same, by the way.

Comment: You need `do |memo, (section, stories)|...`. Also, I suggest using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) (introduced in v1.9) rather than `inject` as you then wouldn't need that pesky final `memo`. Note the block arguments are reversed with `each_with_object`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) method. Because you don't change the content size, just change the stories size, so you don't need to clone the content.

```
def remove_empty_stories(content)
    content.each do |section,stories|
        stories.delete_if { |e| e.length < 25 }
    end
end
```